# Hide/unhide a row when a slicer is selected/deselected

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a nested slicer view in a dashboard where two slicers will be right on top of each other in two different rows in Excel.

I want when any options in Slicer1 are selected, to unhide the row that Slicer2 is on. When all options are once again deselected in Slicer1, resetting it to show all data, I would like to once again hide the row that slicer 2 is on.

I have used macro toggles in the past to hide/unhide rows, but I cannot find a solution for this problem.

Edit 2/17/2020

I have another issue that I have encountered. I am using this code on a couple of different tabs. One tab works fine - it is setup to call the macro from a module when the pivot updates, and the pivot is on another sheet from the slicer.

The other one has the pivot on the same sheet that is being updated instead of a different one (I'm not sure that matters). I have the setup the same though - when that pivot updates, it calls the macro. The problem is that there is one region in the slicer, the last one, that does not work. I have 12 regions, and when I select any of them except the one, I get the target row unhidden. When I clear the filters, it hides again. But this one region behaves like I am clearing them all. If the row is already hidden, nothing happens, but if the row is already showing, then it hides it. Here is the current code:

```
Sub Hide_Unhide_facility2()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim cache As Excel.SlicerCache
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim sItem As Excel.SlicerItem

Set cache = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Region2")

For Each sItem In cache.SlicerItems
Rows(10).Hidden = sItem.Selected

Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue with this code:

```
Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate _
    (ByVal Target As PivotTable)

Dim cache As Excel.SlicerCache
Set cache = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Region1")
Dim sItem As Excel.SlicerItem

For Each sItem In cache.SlicerItems
    If sItem.Selected = True Then
    Rows(69).Hidden = True
    End If

    If sItem.Selected = False Then
    Rows(69).Hidden = False
    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Hope this helps someone down the line.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. You should try [RubberduckVBA](http://rubberduckvba.com/) to get useful hinrs to improve your code. E.g.`Rows`refers implicit to`ActiveSheet` and the If conditions are obsolete. Just use `Rows(69).Hidden = sItem.Selected`

Comment: @ComputerVersteher Thank you so much, I changed the code to that simpler method and it works. I have another issue though, and am editing the issue to explain. If you have any ideas on that, I would really appreciate it.